# I want to learn about -1/12

Tags: summation, euler-maclaurin, ramanujan-summation

I am completely fascinated by the Euler/Ramanujan result

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n = -\frac{1}{12}$$

It is amazing to me that there are so many seemingly bogus ways to evaluate this, and they all give the same ridiculous answer.  It's magical.  I want to understand what's going on here more deeply.

I have been reading up on the [Euler-MacLaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), [Ramanujan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), and the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula), but wikipedia does not go into much depth.   Where can I find what I need to understand and prove these results?  I have an undergrad degree in math, but still get quickly lost in most research-level papers.

Comment: I haven't read it carefully, but Terry Tao had a blog post about it once.  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/